# jQuery.ui is undefined when I try to use IgGrid with Webpack

Tags: angular, jquery-ui, webpack, ignite-ui, iggrid

I try to use IgGrid Ignite UI with Webpack but i have the flowing error :

TypeError: jQuery.ui is undefined

Despite i have the jquery and jquery_ui in my package.json

I found a solution to build jquery thanks to:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
```

but not Jquery-ui

Answer (score 2):

Install jquery-ui-bundle package and include it to alias in webpack config
alias:

```
{
  "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/build/release.js",
  ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work. however i installed two packages : jquery-ui and jquery-ui-bundle  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1", "jquery-ui-bundle": "^1.12.1",and alias add \n alias: {
            "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/build/release.js",

        },

Comment: when i try to require jquery-ui in app.component.ts (require('jquery-ui');) i get this error when i compile with Webpack: ERROR in ./~/jquery-ui/build/release.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'download.jqueryui.com/lib/package-1-12-themes' in '/home/anouar99pac/pyramidEnv/ihm_v2/ihm/static/app_ng2/node_modules/jquery-ui/build'
 @ ./~/jquery-ui/build/release.js 60:15-73
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts

Comment: How about using jquery-ui-bundle in alias:      alias: {
        'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.js'
      },